# How to make the whole grid clickable on bootstrap?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following method to show next and previous post on WordPress using bootstrap.

```
<div class="row ">
<div class=" col-xs-5"><?php next_post('%', '', 'yes'); ?></div>
<div class=" col-xs-5"><?php previous_post('%', '', 'yes'); ?></div>
</div>
```

The link is click-able and it works but I want to make the whole grid for each link click-able.